# npm issue while Installing vue-cli globally

Tags: npm, vue.js, vue-cli

I got 'npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY' while I am trying to install vue-cli globally using 'npm install -g vue-cli' command on windows 7. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

running 'npm i -g npm' command solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
  `npm cache verify`

Or update npm :
  `npm i -g npm`